# because of + clause

Tags: translation, preposition, conjunction

How would I say *I don't like drinking Cola because of how unhealthy it is*?

> Ich trinke nicht gern Cola, wegen wie ungesund es ist.

or

> Ich trinke nicht gern Cola, weil wie ungesund es ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This grammatical construction in English – using clauses without conjunction as parts of other clauses or as attributes to nonexisting nouns – is not possible in German. In this case `how unhealty it is` is a whole subclause incorporated into the clause `because of how unhealthy it is` without a conjunction or as a relative clause to a noun, which doesn't exist in the clause. In German, you would need such a conjunction or noun. Furthermore, the `because of …`-clause cannot be translated into German as a clause, because it misses a verb (The `is` is part of the subclause, not of the `because of …`-clause itself.).

The grammatically closest translation, that I can think of, is:

> Ich trinke nicht gern Cola wegen des Grades, wie ungesund sie ist.

The `because of` is translated as `wegen` like you did yourself. But `wegen` demands a nominal construction, not a clause, in German. A suitable noun would be `Grad`, which than can get an attribute translating `how unhealthy it is`. This is done by a relative clause.

But this translation is uncommon. One would rather say:

> Ich trinke nicht gerne Cola, weil sie so ungesund ist.
>
> Ich trinke nicht gerne Cola wegen ihrer Gesundheitsschädlichkeit. (Best translation for `unhealthyness` as `Ungesundheit` is a made up word. Thank you, Uwe.)
>
> Ich trinke nicht gerne Cola wegen ihrer negativen Auswirkungen auf meine Gesundheit.
>
> Ich trinke nicht gerne Cola, weil sie nicht gut für die Gesundheit ist. (Dank an Em1 für dieses Beispiel.)

Comment: @Toscho Allerdings ist "gesundheitsschädlich" nach meinem Sprachgefühl etwas stärker als "ungesund". Bei "ungesund" denke ich an Cola oder Pommes Frites, bei "gesundheitsschädlich" eher an Nikotin, Quecksilber oder Asbest.

Comment: @Uwe Das kann sein, aber gibt es diese Unterscheidung um Englischen auch? So gut kann ich nicht Englisch, aber ich würde `unhealthy` in beiden Fällen benutzen.

Answer (score 5):

> Ich trinke nicht gern Cola, weil sie so ungesund ist.

Sie, die Cola.

> Ich trinke nicht gern Cola, weil es so ungesund ist.

Es, das Trinken.

So oder so: So.

Comment: "Sie, die Cola" kann aber je nach Region noch einige Diskussionen zur Folge haben :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Ja, da wo man auch "Das Lisbeth" sagt, schon.

Comment: Schtümmt. *Die* Cola ist im Süden Neutrum.